# ng-transclude as: element vs attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion, angularjs-ng-transclude

I want to create a wrapper directive that would serve as the frame for a notification widget in a list. In that frame I want to transclude later some specific content based on a property from the `notif` object. Currently I hard coded a `div` element.

I have the following in index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="notificationCenterCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="notif in allNotifications">
            <notification-base notification="notif" remove="removeNotification(notif)">
                <div style="background-color: fuchsia">bla bla</div> 
            </notification-base>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the directive spec:

```
ns.directive("notificationBase", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/notification-base.html',
        controller: 'notificationBaseCtrl',
        scope: {
            notification: '=',
            removeNotif: '&remove'
        }
    };
});
```

**Why does the following work**, that is it displays the transcluded `div` in fuchsia background?

```
<div>
    My notification title: {{notification.name}}
    <div ng-transclude id="notificationContent">

    </div>
    <a ng-click="remove()">Remove</a>
</div>
```

...but if i use it like an element the fuchsia div no longer shows up.

```
<div>
    My notification title: {{notification.name}}
    <div id="notificationContent">
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="remove()">Remove</a>
</div>
```

What is the difference if I use `ng-transclude` as an attribute or an element. (I use Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only recently (since this [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8141)) `ngTransclude` directive supports usage as `element`.

You are probably using angular with version < `1.3` where `ngTransclude` used as `element` **is not supported** - the primary reason for this being [IE8 support](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8141#issuecomment-48931674).